# Flex/ActionScript 3: Overriding parameter names in data service's superclass

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder, overriding, superclass

Using Flash Builder I need to create a data service with 2 parameters named **start-index** and **max-results** (for the YouTube API). In Flash Builder/Flex data services, parameter names can only contain letters, numbers and underscores. I temporarily used **startIndex** and **maxResults** intending to override these in the service's superclass using its child class. It turns out it is not as simple as I thought and I have tried this numerous ways. If I overwrite the parameter names in the superclass it works fine, but this is inevitably overwritten because it is auto-generated. This is the superclass, **_Super_TopRatedService.as** :

```
package services.topratedservice
{
**(imports here)**

[ExcludeClass]
internal class _Super_TopRatedService extends com.adobe.fiber.services.wrapper.HTTPServiceWrapper
{
    private static var serializer0:XMLSerializationFilter = new XMLSerializationFilter();

    // Constructor
    public function _Super_TopRatedService()
    {
        // initialize service control
        _serviceControl = new mx.rpc.http.HTTPMultiService();
         var operations:Array = new Array();
         var operation:mx.rpc.http.Operation;
         var argsArray:Array;

         operation = new mx.rpc.http.Operation(null, "getData");
         operation.url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated";
         operation.method = "GET";
         argsArray = new Array("startIndex","maxResults");
         operation.argumentNames = argsArray;         
         operation.serializationFilter = serializer0;
         operation.properties = new Object();
         operation.properties["xPath"] = "/::entry";
         operation.resultElementType = valueObjects.Entry;
         operations.push(operation);

         _serviceControl.operationList = operations;  


         preInitializeService();
         model_internal::initialize();
    }        
    //init initialization routine here, child class to override
    protected function preInitializeService():void
    {

    }    
    /**
      * This method is a generated wrapper used to call the 'getData' operation. It returns an mx.rpc.AsyncToken whose 
      * result property will be populated with the result of the operation when the server response is received. 
      * To use this result from MXML code, define a CallResponder component and assign its token property to this method's return value. 
      * You can then bind to CallResponder.lastResult or listen for the CallResponder.result or fault events.
      *
      * @see mx.rpc.AsyncToken
      * @see mx.rpc.CallResponder 
      *
      * @return an mx.rpc.AsyncToken whose result property will be populated with the result of the operation when the server response is received.
      */
    public function getData(startIndex:int, maxresults:int) : mx.rpc.AsyncToken
    {
        var _internal_operation:mx.rpc.AbstractOperation = _serviceControl.getOperation("getData");
        var _internal_token:mx.rpc.AsyncToken = _internal_operation.send(startIndex,maxresults) ;
        return _internal_token;
    }         
}
```

You can see the parameter names in the line **argsArray = new Array("startIndex","maxResults");**

This is the child class, **TopRatedService.as** :

```
package services.topratedservice
{    
public class TopRatedService extends _Super_TopRatedService
{
    /**
     * Override super.init() to provide any initialization customization if needed.
     */
    protected override function preInitializeService():void
    {
        super.preInitializeService();
        // Initialization customization goes here
    }                   
}    
}
```

How and where should I override this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was the way it was supposed to be done in **TopRatedService.as** :

```
protected override function preInitializeService():void
    {
        super.preInitializeService();
        // Initialization customization goes here
        super._serviceControl.operations.getData.argumentNames= new Array("start-index","max-results")
    }
```